# Performing Calculations SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take information from one MySQL table, perform a bunch of calculations on this data, and then put the results in a second MySQL table. What would be the best way of doing this (i.e. in MySQL itself, using python, etc.)?

My apologies for the vagueness, I'll try to be more specific. Table 1 has every meal that every person in my class eats, so each meal is a primary key, and other columns include the person and the number of calories. The primary key for Table 2 is the person, and another column is the percentage of total calories this person has eaten, out of the calories of the entire class. Another column is the percentage of total calories of this person's gender in the class. Every day, I want to take the new eating information, and use it to update the percentages in Table 2. (Thanks for the help!)

Comment: Please include table structure

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that (sorry, I'm new to MySQL).

Comment: If you specify what columns the table has, it'll be easier to understand and discuss.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be that you create a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) or a `Materialized View` with the complex SELECT query behind it.

The `Materialized View` could be an other option too, as you have wrote that you would like to have these results re-queried/refreshed every day.

If you need to do more advanced operations on those tables, you could create a [Stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) and call it when you need its data.

**Note:** you can't work furthermore (eg.: can't call it from a select for joining it's result set) with the procedures result set other than say a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Assming the calculations can be done in SQL (and percentages are definitely do-able), you have some choices.

The first, and academically correct, choice, is not to store this in a table at all. One of the principles of [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is that you don't store duplicate or calculated values - instead, you calculate them as you need them.

This isn't just an academic concern - it avoids many silly bugs and anomalies, and it means your data is always up to date - you don't have to wait for your calculation query to run before you can use the data.

If the calculation is non-trivial and/or an essential part of the business domain, common practice is to create a database [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29), which behaves like a table when queried, but is actually calculated on the fly. This means that the business logic is encapsulated in the view, rather than repeated in multiple queries. You can go further, with materialized views etc. - but the basic principle is the same.

In some cases, where the volume of data is huge, or the calculations are time consuming, or you have calculations that are very hard to embed in a single SQL statement, it's common to create "aggregate tables" - this is what you are suggesting. You can populate these tables either by (scheduled) queries, or by using database triggers.

However, aggregate tables are a last resort - they make the solution *much* harder to maintain and debug - if the data is wrong, you don't have a single query to debug, you've got to follow the chain of logic all the way through.

Assuming you are in a class of a few dozen people, and are reporting on less than 10 million years of meals, any modern RDBMS can calculate this report in milliseconds - there's really no need to store it in an aggregate table.